# is there an easy way to turn a file link into a download button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for example an mp3 file, it's easy to just have the user open it with the browser or save it by right click and left click save link as.

but is there an easy way for the user to just download it with a simple left click? while keeping it at mp3 format.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can have basic html link with `target=_blank` attribute specified for this purpose,

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/music.mp3" target="_blank">Download Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install Greasemonkey on your browser and look for the script on Greasepot that can change a mp3 file into downloadable button.

Answer (score 0):

There is basically nothing you can do in javascript in the web page that does this. The way download link work is to set a HTTP header on the server. The header that changes a regular resource into a downloadable resource is `Content-disposition`. Specifically you need to send it as:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=music_file_name.mp3
```

This forces the browser to do a "save as" rather than trying to display the file.

Obviously how you set this header depends on your server or framework or programming language or all three. Here's an example on how to do this in PHP:

```
http_send_content_disposition("music_file_name.mp3");
http_send_file("music_file_name.mp3");
```

Note that the link in HTML remains the same, no changes necessary. You could even download using form submission:

```
<a href="music_file_name.mp3">Download</a>

<form action="music_file_name.mp3">
    <input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>
```

It really doesn't matter how the browser request the file. As long as `Content-disposition` is set as "attachment" it will display a "save as" dialog to save the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can make download page (PHP), and place it in the folder with your mp3 file.
in download page write this:

```
<?
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename= your_file.mp3);
readfile(your_file.mp3);
?>
```

Rename your_file.mp3 with real name of mp3 file. Then just place link to your download page that you just created. When you click on link, file will be downloaded.